How to create a simple "Hello world" KWin Script for KDE Plasma 6.0?
I could not find sample code, so A.I. gave me the code for main.qml. For metadata, I copied it from https://develop.kde.org/docs/plasma/kwin/ . The problem is that System Settings says that the packaging is invalid. It doesn't tell what exactly is wrong. What is wrong and how to fix it?
metadata.json
{
    "KPlugin": {
        "Name": "My Script",
        "Description": "Description of the script",
        "Icon": "preferences-system-windows",
        
        "Authors": [
            {
                "Email": "username@gmail.com",
                "Name": "Firstname Lastname"
            }
        ],
        "Id": "myscript",
        "Version": "1.0",
        "License": "GPLv3",
        "Website": "https://github.com/username/myscript"
    },
    "X-Plasma-API": "declarativescript",
    "X-Plasma-MainScript": "code/main.qml",
    "KPackageStructure": "KWin/Script"
}

main.qml
// main.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import org.kde.kwin 2.0

Item {
    // This item will be the parent for the text display
    anchors.fill: parent

    Text {
        id: helloText
        text: "Hello"
        y: 50 // Adjust the position as needed
        x: (parent.width - width) / 2 // Center horizontally
        font.pixelSize: 24 // Adjust font size as needed
    }
}

// This QML file should be part of a KWin script package.
// Refer to the KWin scripting tutorial for packaging details.


I created the package file by just compressing files into a ZIP file and changing the extension.


This is the way to test a KWin script via Shell Script (BASH) interactively using Dbus "org.kde.KWin" commands.
This script will print "Hello, World!" to the KWin logs, which you can view using...
journalctl --user -u plasma-kwin_wayland.service -f


#!/bin/bash

# ABOUT: Test a KWin script via Shell Script (BASH) interactively using Dbus "org.kde.KWin"
# commands.

# Remove the "hello_world.js" KWin script file in case of a previous unsuccessful
# execution.
rm -f /tmp/hello_world.js

# Set the content of the KWin script file "hello_world.js" via Shell.
read -r -d '' HELLO_WORLD_JS << 'HEREDOC'
BEGIN
print("Hello, World!");

END
HEREDOC

# Remove the "BEGIN" and "END" delimiters. The "BEGIN" and "END" delimiters make
# organization easier and allow for blank lines at the end of the file.
HELLO_WORLD_JS=${HELLO_WORLD_JS:6:-3}

# Create the KWin script file "hello_world.js".
echo -n "$HELLO_WORLD_JS" > /tmp/hello_world.js

# Load the KWin script file "hello_world.js".
qdbus org.kde.KWin /Scripting org.kde.kwin.Scripting.loadScript "/tmp/hello_world.js" "hello_world"

# Starts the KWin Script that was just loaded.
qdbus org.kde.KWin /Scripting org.kde.kwin.Scripting.start

# Remove the KWin script file "hello_world.js" as it is no longer needed.
rm -f /tmp/hello_world.js

# Unload the "hello_world.js" KWin script file as it is no longer needed.
qdbus org.kde.KWin /Scripting org.kde.kwin.Scripting.unloadScript "hello_world"

exit 0

